# ZF, How to generate Entities with Doctrine 2

Tags: database, zend-framework

I recently decided to try Doctrine 2.
I manage to partially integrate it to Zend. The command line works and I manage to interrogate the database.
The problem comes with the generation of my differents entities, proxies,...

Before, with Doctrine 1.x, we could generate, start with our database, the YML files and business classes.

Now, with Doctrine 2, we have to generate entities from mapping files(metadata in YML,XML,...). But files can't be generated from the DB with Doctrine 2 (I found nothing on it...).

So, I created DB YML files with mysql Workbench. But these files are not compatibles with Doctrine 2.

Fortunately, the doctrine command have some utility to convert the YML. But i get an other problem : I don't find it or help on it!

Maybe someone know Doctrine 2 better than me and could help me?
My problem when converting is :

```
Could not map doctrine 1 type 'float'!
```

This is the YML part which seem to have a problem:

```
  tVenue:
  tableName: t_venues
  columns:
    ven_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    ven_title:
      type: string(250)
      default: null
    ven_adress:
      type: clob(65535)
      notnull: true
    ven_zip:
      type: string(10)
      notnull: true
    cit_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
    cit_label:
      type: string(150)
      notnull: true
    ven_lat:
      type : float
      default: null
    ven_long:
      type : float
      default: null
  indexes:
    cit_id:
      fields: [cit_id]
  options:
    charset: utf8
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I check thas this declaration was standard to Doctrine 1.

Did someone have an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the float problem:

Try `decimal` in stead of `float`, it maps to a PHP double.

Comment: Thanks zwip,
it's fixed and the YML was generated but i want to generate entities with my own prefixe
example:
"news" ---> "model_news"

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented new command for generating entities from database, please check https://github.com/umpirsky/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/GenerateEntitiesDbCommand.php

Just add it like:

```
$cli->addCommands(array(
// DBAL Commands
new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand(),
new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand(),

// ORM Commands
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\MetadataCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\ResultCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\QueryCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\DropCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\EnsureProductionSettingsCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertDoctrine1SchemaCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateRepositoriesCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateEntitiesCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateEntitiesDbCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateProxiesCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertMappingCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\RunDqlCommand(),
new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ValidateSchemaCommand(),
```

));

Comment: Or use doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Skipper](http://www.skipper18.com/) as an alternative way to generate Yaml/Xml/Annotations from visual model.

It fully supports Doctrine2 so the generated schema files will be ready-to-use and as a bonus you can edit ORM specific properties directly in the visual model. All you need to do will be handled by one tool.